# Robolinux Live on Dell 5559 i7 6500U firmware error

Tags: debian, bluetooth, intel, firmware

Trying to run Robolinux Live on DVD on new Dell 5559 i7 6500U to test before install, but it won't run.

Getting error:

```
57.647930 bluetooth: hci0 failed to open intel firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw.101.2d.d.bseq(-12).
```

I'm new to Linux (although fairly techie), migrating from horrible Win10 Home!!! Is there some way to get this to work to try Robolinux, being my chosen Linux distro being blown away by impressive videos & having already tested Mint & Elementary, which are okay, but Robo does it for me from what I've seen.

Have tried updating BIOS & Win drivers, but nothing works. Need to test prior to install to get away from Win10, but still have good access to some vital Win programs not supported in Wine or Playonlinux.

Can anyone help by suggesting a version of Robo which will work, or can it be made to work?

I am not currently using Linux, but I want to migrate to Linux from Windows. First though, I want to boot Robolinux Live on a boot DVD to test run Robolinux to be sure it's the distro I need prior to installing. Above is the error message I get & it won't even load from the DVD.

I did change BIOS to Legacy Boot, & it boots with Mint & Elementary DVDs no problem, but something in Debian seems to be the problem. I am really keen to use Robolinux so I'm wondering what I can do to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Welcome to U&L please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/359499/edit) by adding the output of `sudo lspci` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: if you can't boot from the cd/usb try to disable the secure boot